# List of possible combinations from multiple vectors

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to generate all possible cominations (length 3) for the below data.
The trick is - we do not want Variables from the the same Stage together.
E.g: select 1 variable from Stage1, one from Stage2 and one from Stage 3 or one from Stage 1, one from Stage 4 and one from Stage 5.
I was trying to use 'combn" funciton - but it seems to be not ok, I have started working with the expand.grid but not sure on the next steps

My below code:

```
Stage1<-paste0("VarStage1_", seq(1:6))
Stage2<-paste0("VarStage2_", seq(1:8))
Stage3<-paste0("VarStage3_", seq(1:3))
Stage4<-paste0("VarStage4_", seq(1:4))
Stage5<-paste0("VarStage5_", seq(1:6))

new<-combn(c(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5, Stage5), 3)
head(t(new)) # not ok, 3 variables from Stage 1 (VarStage1_1,VarStage1_2,VarStage1_3)

my.combinations<-expand.grid(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3) # I can manually add all combinations here eg.: Stage1, Stage2, Stage5
head(my.combinations)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?
Put the vectors in a list, create a combinations index and `apply` `expand.grid` to each sublist.

```r
Stage1<-paste0("VarStage1_", seq(1:6))
Stage2<-paste0("VarStage2_", seq(1:8))
Stage3<-paste0("VarStage3_", seq(1:3))
Stage4<-paste0("VarStage4_", seq(1:4))
Stage5<-paste0("VarStage5_", seq(1:6))

vec_list <- list(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5, Stage5)
inx <- combn(length(vec_list), 3)
result <- apply(inx, 2, \(i) expand.grid(vec_list[i]))
lapply(result, head, n = 6)
#> [[1]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage2_1 VarStage5_1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage1_1 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage1_2 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage1_3 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage1_4 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage1_5 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage1_6 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 2 VarStage2_2 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 3 VarStage2_3 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 4 VarStage2_4 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 5 VarStage2_5 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 6 VarStage2_6 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage2_1 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage2_2 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage2_3 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage2_4 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage2_5 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage2_6 VarStage3_1 VarStage5_1
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage2_1 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage2_2 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage2_3 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage2_4 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage2_5 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage2_6 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>          Var1        Var2        Var3
#> 1 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 2 VarStage3_2 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 3 VarStage3_3 VarStage4_1 VarStage5_1
#> 4 VarStage3_1 VarStage4_2 VarStage5_1
#> 5 VarStage3_2 VarStage4_2 VarStage5_1
#> 6 VarStage3_3 VarStage4_2 VarStage5_1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Like [Allan Cameron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411532/list-of-possible-combinations-from-multiple-vectors/75411654?noredirect=1#comment133061186_75411654) says, to have all results in one data.frame,

```
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: I was halfway through posting the same answer! Except doing `do.call(rbind, .)` on the result to get a single data frame.

Comment: @AllanCameron I have added the `do.call` line to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
One quick question: for the line with apply I have an error: Unexpected input in "result<-apply (". So, I have changed the line to the below: 
result <- apply(inx, 2, function(i) expand.grid(vec_list[i])). Do you mayby know what was a root cause? Am I missing any specific R package etc?

Comment: @Lohengrin The new lambda functions ```\(i)``` were introduced in R 4.1, your version of R is probably older, only `function(i)` was available. Since R is for free, time to update?

Answer (score 2):

The brute force approach would be to generate all combinations, then subset to those with elements from 3 different stages.

```
new <- combn(c(Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5), 3)

n_stages <- apply(
  new, 
  2, 
  \(x) length(unique(gsub("_\\d+$", "", x)))
)

new <- new[, n_stages == 3]

head(t(new))
```

```
     [,1]          [,2]          [,3]         
[1,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage3_1"
[2,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage3_2"
[3,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage3_3"
[4,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage4_1"
[5,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage4_2"
[6,] "VarStage1_1" "VarStage2_1" "VarStage4_3”
```